# ProgressDialog in AsyncTask called from DialogFragment is not shown

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progress-bar, progressdialog

I am executing an AsyncTask from inside a DialogFragment but the progress bar is not shown during doInBackground. Here is the code:

```
public class GetCustomerSoapAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>
{
  ProgressDialog prg;
  ActionBarActivity activity;
  GetResponseFromGetCustomer listener;


  public GetCustomerSoapAsync(ActionBarActivity activity, GetResponseFromGetCustomer listener)
  {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.listener = listener;
    prg = new ProgressDialog(activity);
    prg.setMessage("Lütfen Bekleyin");
    Log.i("ED","Progress will be shown");
    prg.show();

  }



  @Override protected String doInBackground(Void... params)
  {
    //some stuff
  }

  @Override protected void onPostExecute(String s)
  {
    listener.getResponseFromGetCustomer(s);

    if (prg.isShowing())
    {
        prg.dismiss();
    }

 }
```

and where I call it:

```
public class B1_PhoneNumberFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment
{
 ...
  buttonLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
          ...


          PhoneNumberVerified dialog = new PhoneNumberVerified();
                dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "NumberVerifiedByUser");

        }
        ...
    }
   ....



  public class PhoneNumberVerified extends DialogFragment
  {

   @Override
   public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
     // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
     AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
     // Format of this dialog will be changed
     builder.setMessage("Numaranız doğru mu?\n" + "0" + number)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                        {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                int id)
                            {
                                GlobalApplication.getUser().setPhone(
                                        (excludeParanthesis
                                                (number)));

                                //AsyncTask is not working properly,
                                // progress dialog is not shown and code flows before
                                // response is set to s
                                GetCustomerSoapAsync getCustomerSoapAsync =
                                        new GetCustomerSoapAsync(
                                                (ActionBarActivity) getActivity(),
                                                new GetResponseFromGetCustomer()

                                                {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void getResponseFromGetCustomer
                                                            (String s)
                                                    {
                                                        response = s;
                                                    }
                                                });

                                getCustomerSoapAsync.execute();


                                Log.i("ED", "Response after GetCustomerSoapAsync callback: " +
                                            response);

}
```

And finally, maybe because of the flawed flow of the tasks or maybe something else, the callback can't do its job, and response is not set to return value of the AsyncTask.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() { //pgd });}

Answer (score 2):

You should use `onPreExecute` :

```
class Task1 extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, String []> {

    /** The Progress dialog. */
    private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(YourActivity.this);


    /**
     * Set the Progress dialog.
     */
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
    super.onPreExecute();
    this.dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    this.dialog.show();
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    }


    protected String[] doInBackground(Object... params) {
        ///
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String [] result) 
    {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        this.dialog.dismiss();
    }

}
```

To call it you should:

```
Task1 myTask = new Task1();    
myTask.execute(stopArrey, start, end);
```

Hope it helped! :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to operate on the ProgressDialog only on the UI Thread.

The constructor on the asynctask gives great flexibility enough to put the task in it's own class.  Note: It's important that any field that is initialized in the Constructor on your custom AsyncTask takes advantage of the java final keyword so the field variables get automatic null for garbage collection.

Solution ProgressDialog code needs to be invoked in onPreExecute() where the task is still on the UI thread.

```
public class GetCustomerSoapAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>
{
ProgressDialog prg;
// use final for fields initialized in a constructor.
final ActionBarActivity activity;
final GetResponseFromGetCustomer listener;
```

//The example below passes in the ProgressDialog from the caller where it's already shown.  Pass it in to have access in the async tasks publish Progress method.  Dismiss the ProgressDialog in the listener method;  You didn't show your listener so this is just a technique

```
 public GetCustomerSoapAsync(ActionBarActivity activity, GetResponseFromGetCustomer     listener, ProgressDialog prg)
{
  this.activity = activity;
  this.listener = listener;
  this.prg = prg;

 // or move this code to onPreExecute() where it runs on the UI thread.
// move this code to onPreExecute() 
//prg = new ProgressDialog(activity);
//prg.setMessage("Lütfen Bekleyin");
//Log.i("ED","Progress will be shown");
//prg.show();

}
```

Comment: Let me give my comments together here danny117 and @SeahawksRdaBest:
I tried what you suggested but still no luck, I am updating my question because I think  the problem is that I am trying to show a progress bar while I am in a dialog fragment inside a fragment. I even tried to delete prg.dismiss() in onPostExecute to see what happens, still no progress bar. Interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Ok the issue I believe is you have to declare the PD in the layout visible to the user before the Aysnch task is executing.

For example:

```
//Declare the pd here. Pd private to class.
private ProgressDialog pd;
    builder.setMessage("Numaranız doğru mu?\n" + "0" + number)
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes,
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                            {
                              ....
                             pd = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "",
                            "Your Message Here!!!", false);
                            // Now using a modified constructor call your execute function
                           //Previous parametes + pd
                           GetCustomerSoapAsync gCSA = new GetCustomerSoapAsync(...,...,pd);
                           getCustomerSoapAsync.execute();

    }
```

Then in your Asynch class:

```
public class GetCustomerSoapAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>
{
  ProgressDialog prg;
  ActionBarActivity activity;
  GetResponseFromGetCustomer listener;


      public GetCustomerSoapAsync(ActionBarActivity activity, GetResponseFromGetCustomer listener,ProgressDialog pd)
      ProgressDialog prg;
      {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.listener = listener;
        this.prg = pd;

      }



      @Override protected String doInBackground(Void... params)
      {
        //some stuff
      }

      @Override protected void onPostExecute(String s)
      {
        listener.getResponseFromGetCustomer(s);

        if (prg.isShowing())
        {
            prg.dismiss();
        }

     }
```

Ps: I don't know if you are using fragments as a implementation but if you are you must refer to the same pd you called in the onclick function in the fragment via rootview else you might be calling functions on a progresss dialog that never showed in the first place.